# Why won't Vim source my .vimrc at startup?

Tags: vim, environment-variables, latex, vimrc

**Note:  edited to provide more info.**

I have modified my `~/.vimrc` significantly (although some of my initial modifications I made in the system-wide `/etc/vim/vimrc`).  It probably doesn't matter either way since I am really the only user on my laptop, and certainly the only one who edits in Vim.

Anyway, with the Vim-LaTeX package, files open with folds automatically inserted at sections and subsections of `.tex` documents.  This is fine (and useful once in a while) as long as the folds are all open when I start.  The following two lines seem to accomplish what I want *when the `.vimrc` is sourced!*

```
set foldmethod=syntax
autocmd Syntax tex normal zR
```

My frustrating workaround has been to manually source `.vimrc` when I open a document to begin editing (or at least invoking `zR` manually to open all the folds).

---

My cascading question is:

**Is there an environmental variable that I can set (in my `.bash_profile`, say) that tells Vim to look for `.vimrc` in my home directory?  Shouldn't this be the default?  How do I fix this?**

---

**EDIT:**  I haven't been able to resolve this.  I've included the verbose output of `vim -V`.  It looks as if my `~/.vimrc` is being sourced, but then perhaps other stuff is "overwriting" it in memory?

```
chdir(/home/sammy)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/home/sammy/.vimrc"
Searching for "debian.vim" in "/home/sammy/.vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/home/sammy/.vim/after"
Searching for "/home/sammy/.vim/debian.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/debian.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim"
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74)
fchdir() to previous dir
line 10: sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim
continuing in /home/sammy/.vimrc
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/debian.vim"
Searching for "/home/sammy/.vim/after/debian.vim"
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax)
fchdir() to previous dir
line 20: sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim"
Searching for "syntax/synload.vim" in "/home/sammy/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,/home/sammy/.vim/after"
Searching for "/home/sammy/.vim/syntax/synload.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/syntax/synload.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/syntax/synload.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim"
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax)
fchdir() to previous dir
line 19: sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim"
Searching for "syntax/syncolor.vim" in "/home/sammy/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,/home/sammy/.vim/after"
Searching for "/home/sammy/.vim/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim"
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax)
fchdir() to previous dir
line 21: sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
continuing in /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/home/sammy/.vim/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
continuing in /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
Searching for "filetype.vim" in "/home/sammy/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,/home/sammy/.vim/after"
Searching for "/home/sammy/.vim/filetype.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/filetype.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/filetype.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim"
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74)
fchdir() to previous dir
line 25: sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim"
Searching for "ftdetect/*.vim" in "/home/sammy/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,/home/sammy/.vim/after"
Searching for "/home/sammy/.vim/ftdetect/*.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/ftdetect/*.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftdetect/*.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftdetect/*.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/ftdetect/*.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/after/ftdetect/*.vim"
Searching for "/home/sammy/.vim/after/ftdetect/*.vim"
not found in 'runtimepath': "ftdetect/*.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
continuing in /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/filetype.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/after/filetype.vim"
Searching for "/home/sammy/.vim/after/filetype.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
continuing in /home/sammy/.vimrc
Searching for "syntax/syncolor.vim" in "/home/sammy/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,/home/sammy/.vim/after"
Searching for "/home/sammy/.vim/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim"
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax)
fchdir() to previous dir
line 25: sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
continuing in /home/sammy/.vimrc
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "/home/sammy/.vim/after/syntax/syncolor.vim"
Searching for "filetype.vim" in "/home/sammy/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,/home/sammy/.vim/after"
Searching for "/home/sammy/.vim/filetype.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/filetype.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/filetype.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim"
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74)
fchdir() to previous dir
line 28: sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
continuing in /home/sammy/.vimrc
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/filetype.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/after/filetype.vim"
Searching for "/home/sammy/.vim/after/filetype.vim"
Searching for "ftplugin.vim" in "/home/sammy/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,/home/sammy/.vim/after"
Searching for "/home/sammy/.vim/ftplugin.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/ftplugin.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftplugin.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim"
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74)
fchdir() to previous dir
line 28: sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
continuing in /home/sammy/.vimrc
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/ftplugin.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/after/ftplugin.vim"
Searching for "/home/sammy/.vim/after/ftplugin.vim"
Searching for "indent.vim" in "/home/sammy/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,/home/sammy/.vim/after"
Searching for "/home/sammy/.vim/indent.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/indent.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/indent.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim"
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74)
fchdir() to previous dir
line 28: sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim
continuing in /home/sammy/.vimrc
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/indent.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/after/indent.vim"
Searching for "/home/sammy/.vim/after/indent.vim"
finished sourcing /home/sammy/.vimrc
Searching for "plugin/**/*.vim" in "/home/sammy/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,/home/sammy/.vim/after"
Searching for "/home/sammy/.vim/plugin/**/*.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/plugin/**/*.vim"
chdir(/var/lib/vim/addons/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/var/lib/vim/addons/plugin/SyntaxFolds.vim"
finished sourcing /var/lib/vim/addons/plugin/SyntaxFolds.vim
chdir(/var/lib/vim/addons/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/var/lib/vim/addons/plugin/filebrowser.vim"
finished sourcing /var/lib/vim/addons/plugin/filebrowser.vim
chdir(/var/lib/vim/addons/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/var/lib/vim/addons/plugin/imaps.vim"
finished sourcing /var/lib/vim/addons/plugin/imaps.vim
chdir(/var/lib/vim/addons/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/var/lib/vim/addons/plugin/libList.vim"
finished sourcing /var/lib/vim/addons/plugin/libList.vim
chdir(/var/lib/vim/addons/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/var/lib/vim/addons/plugin/remoteOpen.vim"
finished sourcing /var/lib/vim/addons/plugin/remoteOpen.vim
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/**/*.vim"
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/**/*.vim"
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
chdir(/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
Searching for "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/plugin/**/*.vim"
Searching for "/var/lib/vim/addons/after/plugin/**/*.vim"
Searching for "/home/sammy/.vim/after/plugin/**/*.vim"
```

Comment: Run `vim` in verbose mode: `vim -V`. This should show when or whether it is sourcing your .vimrc. But it should source your `~/.vimrc` by default. Is it ignoring other settings in `~/.vimrc` as well?

Answer (score 1):

For Unix/Linux, vim looks for `$HOME/.vimrc`, so the first thing that could affect this is, of course, the environment variable `$HOME`.  Is this set on your system (it should be `/home/your_user_name`.

There is no place that I've seen that specifies where this file should be, so the only other way I can see would be if you start with the `-u` option to specify a different .vimrc:

```
-u <vimrc>      Use <vimrc> instead of any .vimrc
-U <gvimrc>     Use <gvimrc> instead of any .gvimrc
```

I suppose you could try using this as a workaround, but it would probably be better to fix the problem, if possible.  I've never had a case where it did not read `.vimrc`.